# Jsoup alternates the given URL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsoup

I'm using spring boot and Jsoup to parse html page.
I'm connecting the page as follows:

```
try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(SOME_URL)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .timeout(5000)
                    .get()   
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Jsoup changes the url parameter from: `name=%F2%EE%E5%F1%20%FA%EE%ED`

to This: `name=%25F2%25EE%25E5%25F1%2520%25FA%25EE%25ED`

The name parameter is in hebrew chars and I convert it to the correct one,
If I paste the given URL in chrome it works, but after I paste the url given from jsoup it's not (I'm taking it from element base url)

How can I force Jsoup to connect to the url without changing it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I Used:

```
url = new URL(SOME_URL);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.connect();
                inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                doc = Jsoup.parse(inputStream, null, WebUtils.WEB_BASE);
```

Seems the null as parameter causes Jsoup to take the charset from the html header